# Explain the output for this program

Tags: c

When I run this code I get an output: `21 20 18 15 11 6`, kindly explain me how we got this output.

```
#define N 6
int main(void)
{
  int i,j,a[N]={1,2,3,4,5,6};

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j<N;j++)
      a[i]+=a[j];

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    printf("%d",a[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You got it because you computed those numbers and then printed them. Although you never print spaces, so I don't actually believe that that's the code that created the output.

Comment: Kindly step through it with a pencil and paper. Its only 6 elements. Or use an interactive debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's easier to understand when you see every outcome inside the second for loop:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[15, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[21, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] now i gets increased

[21, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[21, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[21, 14, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[21, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6] now i gets increased

[21, 20, 7, 4, 5, 6]

[21, 20, 12, 4, 5, 6]

[21, 20, 18, 4, 5, 6] now i gets increased

[21, 20, 18, 9, 5, 6]

[21, 20, 18, 15, 5, 6] now i gets increased

[21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6]

Answer (score 1):

Your program sums elements of array 'a'. First loop determines starting index, inner loop sums up the elements of array (taking into consideration starting index i). At the end, a[0] contains sum of all array's elements, a[1] contains sum of all array's elements starting from index 1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j<N;j++)
        a[i]+=a[j];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("%d",a[i]);
```

a[N]={1,2,3,4,5,6};

doing a trace is the easiest way. N = 6 from the #DEFINE
so the first for loop will be done 6 times

for the first run through

when i = 0 j= 1

a[0] += a[1]

so now a[0] equals 3

j++ so j now equals 2

i = 0 j= 2

a[0] += a[2]

equals a[0] (which is 3) plus a[2] which is 3 this equals 6.

j++ so j now equals 2

if you continue the trace you will see that it is adding up the remainder of the array which is a 1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21

then the next iteration is 2+3+4+5+6

etc.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
for(j=i+1;j<N;j++)
  a[i]+=a[j];
```

value of

```
a[0] = 1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21
a[1] = 2+3+4+5+6 = 20
a[2] = 3+4+5+6 = 18
a[3] = 4+5+6 = 15
a[4] = 5+6 = 11
a[5] = 6 = 6
```

And

```
 printf("%d",a[i]);
```

should be

```
 printf("%d\n",a[i]);
```